# Signalr create two connection to two different hubs

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I have two hubs and I am trying to establish two connections to them from server:

```
    var hubConnection1 = new HubConnection("http://localhost:14382");
    var proxy1 = hubRestaurantConnection.CreateHubProxy("Hub1");
    hubConnection1.Start().Wait();

    var hubConnection2 = new HubConnection("http://localhost:14382");
    var proxy2 = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("Hub2");
    hubConnection2.Start().Wait();
```

hubConnection2.Start().Wait() call allways crashes with exception:

```
    StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
    {
     Transfer-Encoding: chunked
     X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcZGV2XHdlYjJcRmxpcGRpc2hXZWJcRmxpcGRpc2guV2ViXHNpZ25hbHJcc3RhcnQ=?=
     Cache-Control: private
     Date: Wed, 27 May 2015 15:19:49 GMT
     Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
     X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
     X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    }

    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

    Exception Details: Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HttpClientException: StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
    {
     Transfer-Encoding: chunked
     X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcZGV2XHdlYjJcRmxpcGRpc2hXZWJcRmxpcGRpc2guV2ViXHNpZ25hbHJcc3RhcnQ=?=
     Cache-Control: private
     Date: Wed, 27 May 2015 15:19:49 GMT
     Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
     X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
     X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    }
```

The reason why I have two hubs is that one will be used by users with administrator rights, and the second for other users, and it has different methods.

The connection from javascript client seems to work fine. I know that hubs are sharing one connection, but it is no problem from my design perspective. Is it bug or do I do something wrong?

I also tried to swap order of creating hub proxies, and exception happened only on the same proxy.

Comment: "Exception happened only on the same proxy" do you mean the second one or `Hub2`? Also have you attempted to catch the error that is generated server side?

Comment: Yes it happened only on the same proxy (Hub2). I did not catch the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the same HubConnection to create multiple hubproxies:

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:14382");
var proxy1 = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("Hub1");
var proxy2 = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("Hub2");
hubConnection.Start().Wait();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replay, that's true and it would solve the problem as you don't need to call Start().Wait() second time. But I really cannot reproduce the issue now. After I added try - catch, it mysteriously stopped to happen - now I can remove try-catch block, and it works.. :-(